# Where is located the insert method inside the db class in CodeIgniter?

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I'm new of `CodeIgniter` and in the documentation I see that for insert a value into the database is possible call this method:

```
$this->db->insert('ea_appointments', $appointment);
```

Now this method working but I've added to the `$appointment` variable another key, infact the `$appointment` is an associative array. This new key isn't inserted into the database, 'cause the query is skipped by the `db` class? I don't sure of this.

Where is located the insert method? Why my field `resource_id` of `$appointment` array isn't inserted? 
Actually I stay perform some changes to the `easyappointments.org` library. Someone could help me to understand more on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to **insert data** to the table

```
Table Name =  ea_appointments
Values     =  $appointment
```

So query is

```
$appointment = array(
   'title'  => 'My title' ,
   'name'   => 'My Name' ,
   'date'   => 'My date'
);

$this->db->insert('ea_appointments', $appointment);
```

Above query in Normal way

```
INSERT INTO ea_appointments (title, name, date) VALUES ('My title', 'My name', 'My date')
```

---

**Example**

Your table structer

```
|   id  |   name    |   telephone   |   address |   mail    |
|-----------------------------------------------------------|   
|       |           |               |           |           |
```

and you need to insert following values

```
Id          -   1
Name        -   Abdulla
telephone   -   +94755894221
address     -   2444
mail        -   abdullacool04@gmail.com
```

So your Codeigniter insert should be

```
$appointment = array(
    'address'    => '2444'.
    'id'         => 1 ,
    'name'       => 'Abdulla' ,
    'mail'       => 'abdullacool04@gmail.com'
    'telephone'  => '+94755894221'  

);

$this->db->insert('ea_appointments', $appointment);
```

after you run this, it will looks in your table like this

```
|   id  |   name    |   telephone   |   address |   mail    |
|-----------------------------------------------------------|   
|   1   |   Abdulla |   +94755894221|   2444    |   abdullacool04@gmail.com
```

Features in Codeigniter Insert

1. No  Proper order to inserting array `$appointment`
2. Easy to understand

---

**To load the database library** in `config/config.php`

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

So it allow you to use `$this->db` associate funtions

1. [Select](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select)
2. [Insert](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert)
3. [Update](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#update)
4. [Delete](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#delete)

---

**To configure your database**

Goto - `config/databse.php`

In bottom of the page you can configure your databse

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'my_db_name';//database name
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

---

**Some useful Links**

1. [The Database Class](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/index.html)
2. [Auto-loading Resources](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/autoloader.html)
3. [Active Record Class](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Comment: The database is loaded correctly infact when I do: 
$this->db->insert('ea_appointments', $appointment);
The appointment is inserted but the last key of the associative array $appointment isn't inserted. So I'm wondering if there's a class, a method to edit for tell to CodeIgniter framework to add the new value in this table...

Comment: you want know how to insert data??

Comment: Yeah, I want to know how to tell to the method "db->insert" that I've added a new column in the 'ea_appointments' table and also a new key in the $appointment array that I want insert

Comment: There's a way to print the result of: $this->db->insert('ea_appointments', $appointment); I want get in my network response somethings like: INSERT INTO ea_appointments (title, name, date) VALUES ('My title', 'My name', 'My date'). How I can do that?

Comment: all the fields are contain on below **So query is**. check

Comment: So I've understood that the value must be ordinate like the column for insert the value correctly in the column associated?

Comment: no there is no any order. what you have to do is  `'table_filed' => 'value' ,` in here `table_filed` should be **any of table filed name** and `'value'` should be **your value**

Comment: Okay I've fix the problem now but I really don't understand how the insert(); method recognize the appropriate column for insert the value. Could you examplain me better? Maybe with an example, sorry for this, thanks for the support.

Comment: Okay is a bit clear, so if I change the column name and the key of the array to insert is different the value should not be inserted right? Thank you.

Comment: it will not insert data when you enter wrong field or select wrong table

Comment: Please use http://www.codeigniter.com links. Ellislab links left on 2.2.0 version and with last update of year and a half ago are probably not quite suitable for newer made code.

Comment: @Tpojka can you edut it?? Im in mobile now

Comment: I could but you use ellislab links every time. So let's leave this one this way. Next time use codeigniter.com links. Thanks.